# two SharedPreferences isn't working-java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying use two SharedPreferences, the firt is Working, but the second isn't

here is my Java Code

```
public class JogoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


//OTHERS VARIABLES

public TextView txtViewResult,txtCoins, txtTentativas;
private static final String PREF_NAME = "JogoActivityPreferences";
int resulFinalCache,coinsFinalCache;
int count1, count2 ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();


    //methods...

    //MY PROBLEMS START HERE

    txtCoins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCoins);
    txtViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResultado);

    SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    count1 = sp1.getInt("count1", 0);
    txtViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(formatter.format(count1).toString()));//THIS IS WORKING

    SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    count2 = sp2.getInt("count2", 0);
    txtCoins.setText(String.valueOf(formatter.format(count2).toString()));////THIS ISN'T 

}

//Creating methods...

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);//THIS IS WORKING
    count1 = sp1.getInt("count1", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
    editor.putInt("count1", resulFinalCache);
    editor.commit();

    SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);//THIS ISN'T
    count2 = sp2.getInt("count2", 0);
    editor = sp1.edit();
    editor.putInt("count2", coinsFinalCache);
    editor.commit();

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences sp1= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);//THIS IS WORKING
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
    editor.putInt("count1", resulFinalCache);
    editor.commit();

    SharedPreferences sp2= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);//THIS ISN'T
    editor = sp2.edit();
    editor.putInt("count2", coinsFinalCache);
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

every time I launch the app, I use, I close the app and open again, the TextView txtViewResult is working fine, but the txtCoins isn't

I Try use just getPreferences and not getSharedPreferences, but it isn't work too

I try create other Editor, but it isn't work too

Did i do something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is not need to create second reference variable of SharedPreferences, do make sure are you able to save count2 tag in the xml file

Comment: Just one big stupid post in my opinion. I'm thinking he's either trolling or super-high. Who uses 2 sharedPrefs for 2 values :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call getsharedpreferences twice.

Just call it one time and it should be working fine.

E.g your onstop would be

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);//THIS IS WORKING
count1 = sp1.getInt("count1", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
editor.putInt("count1", resulFinalCache);
count2 = sp1.getInt("count2", 0);
editor.putInt("count2", coinsFinalCache);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm. your solution is

```
SharedPreferences sp1_2 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
count1 = sp1_2.getInt("count1", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1_2.edit();
editor.putInt("count1", resulFinalCache);
editor.commit();
count2 = sp1_2.getInt("count2", 0);
editor = sp1_2.edit();
editor.putInt("count2", coinsFinalCache);
editor.commit();
//now both will work
```

infact bind the methods

Answer (score 1):

Generally i can advise you to use simply

For saving:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("name", 1).apply();
```

For reading:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("name", 0);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same name when getting them!
Instead of

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Use two different names like so:

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME1, MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME2, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also you don't need two different shared preferences. Just use one and put those 2 values with different keys.